# Erase value if checkbox is checked

Tags: php

I would like the following:

```
Data = "123";
if checkbox clicked {Data="";}
```

Submit-button

---

That was the best way I could explain it.

I have tried, but I can't get the checkbox to overwrite the data with an empty value.

Comment: That's the best you can explain it?

Comment: I think you have two ways to do that: you can check checkbox status during POST or you have to use javascript...

Comment: lets see what you have for code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form action="form.php" method="post">
<input type="text" value="" name="data" />
<input type="checkbox" value="checkbox" name="checkbox" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

That is your form, and this is your PHP

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    if(isset($_POST['checkbox']))
    {
         $_POST['data'] = "";
    }
    /* the rest of your form */
}
?>
```